# validate SIP (Session Initiation Protocol)

Tags: networking, sip

What are the mechanisms/approaches to validate the UDP payload in case of SIP? SIP message doesn't contain size of header or the body, so how to verify that the payload is valid? In contrast, RTP indicates the size, so given the length value from UDP header it is possible to check RTP for validit and integrity. Can something similar be done for SIP?

Mark.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has two parts:

1. **How do I validate SIP headers?**  The only way to validate SIP headers is to parse them according to the rules of [section 7.3.1 of RFC 3261](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#section-7.3.1).  There are SIP parsers available for many different languages.
2. **How do I validate the body of SIP messages?**  There is a mechanism built into SIP: the `Content-Length` header specifies the size of the body.  In the general case, the body can contain an arbitrary MIME type, and no further validation rules apply.

**Edit:** Per Frank Shearar's comment below, `Content-Length` is not required for SIP messages conveyed via UDP.  But if your UA supports it, you can take advantage of it.

Comment: thanks for comment. However at first I should understand how to verify that the SIP being UDP payload is valid without parsing the whole SIP message -- it may appear to be invalid after parsing 90% of the message. So I'm wondering if there's a quick "test" to make decision about further deep parsing.

Comment: Well, UDP supports integrity verification via checksum, so if the sender populates the checksum field, this could be one quick test.

Comment: SIP messages in UDP datagrams don't require `Content-Length`; if absent, it's assumed the rest of the datagram is the body.

Comment: @Mark What Opensips does (or did before 2.0, I'm not sure about now) is to split logical lines lazily and just make sure they're in "Header: value" format. Then on access to a specific header, the list of (header,value) pairs is parsed from the top until you get to the right one. Value itself is parsed only when you request the details - for example "To: <x> 1@y.com" is only available as text until you specifically request the "To" domain. It's fast, but you have to assume you can get "this is not even a valid message" exception at any point.